# Streaming Video to Web Browser

Tags: javascript, html, video, streaming, video-streaming

I would like to display a live video stream in a web browser. (Compatibility with IE, Firefox, and Chrome would be awesome, if possible.) Someone else will be taking care of streaming the video, but I have to be able to receive and display it. I will be receiving the video over UDP, but for now I am just using VLC to stream it to myself for testing purposes. Is there an open source library that might help me accomplish this using HTML and/or JavaScript? Or a good website that would help me figure out how to do this on my own?

I've read a bit about RTSP, which seems like the traditional option for something like this. That might be what I have to fall back on if I can't accomplish this using UDP, but if that is the case I still am unsure of how to go about this using RTSP/RTMP/RTP, or what the differences between all those acronyms are, if any.

I thought HTTP adaptive streaming might be the best option for a while, but it seemed like all the solutions using that were proprietary (Microsoft IIS Smooth Streaming, Apple HTTP Live Streaming, or Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming), and I wasn't having much luck figuring out how to accomplish it on my own. MPEG-DASH sounded like an awesome solution as well, but it doesn't seem to be in use yet since it is still so new. But now I am told that I should expect to receive the video over UDP anyways, so those solutions probably don't matter for me anymore.

I've been Googling this stuff for several days without much luck on finding anything to help me implement it. All I can find are articles explaining what the technologies are (e.g. RTSP, HTTP Adaptive Streaming, etc.) or tools that you can buy to stream your own videos over the web. Your guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [dynamic adaptive streaming on http](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect that most video sites use FLV,  MP4 is the most widely supported format and it is played via Flash players as well.
The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to open a S3Amzon/cloudFront account and work with JW player.  Then you have access to RTMP software to stream video and audio.  This service is very cheap.  if you want to know more about this, check out these tutorials:
http://www.miracletutorials.com/category/s3-amazon-cloudfront/ Start at the bottom and work your way up to the tutorials higher up.

I hope this will help you get yourself on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorials, they look very thorough and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need sound, you can send JPEGs with header like this:

**Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace**

This is a simple demo with nodejs, it uses library opencv4nodejs to generate images. You can use any other HTTP server which allows to append data to the socket while keeping connection opened. Tested on Chrome and FF on Ubuntu Linux.

To run the sample you will need to install this library with **npm install opencv4nodejs**, it might take while, then start the server like this: **node app.js**, here is app.js itself

```
var http = require('http')
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

var m=new cv.Mat(300, 300, cv.CV_8UC3);
var cnt = 0;
const blue = new cv.Vec3(255, 220, 120);
const yellow = new cv.Vec3(255, 220, 0);
var lastTs = Date.now();
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url=='/'){
        res.end("<!DOCTYPE html><style>iframe {transform: scale(.67)}</style><html>This is a streaming video:<br>" +
            "<img  src='/frame'></img></html>")
    } else if (req.url=='/frame') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary' });
        var x =0;
        var fps=0,fcnt=0;
        var next = function () {
            var ts = Date.now();
            var m1=m.copy();
            fcnt++;
            if (ts-lastTs > 1000){
                lastTs = ts;
                fps = fcnt;
                fcnt=0;
            }
            m1.putText(`frame ${cnt}  FPS=${fps}`, new cv.Point2(20,30),1,1,blue);
            m1.drawCircle(new cv.Point2(x,50),10,yellow,-1);
            x+=1;
            if (x>m.cols) x=0;
            cnt++;
            var buf = cv.imencode(".jpg",m1);
            res.write("--myboundary\r\nContent-type:image/jpeg\r\nDaemonId:0x00258009\r\n\r\n");
            res.write(buf,function () {
                next();
            });
        };
        next();
    }
}).listen(80);
```

A bit later I've found this example with some more details in python: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

**UPDATE**: it also works, if you stream this into html img tag.

Answer (score 0):

True cross-browser streaming is only possible through "rich media" clients like Flash, which is why almost all video websites default to serving video using Adobe's proprietary `.flv` format.

For non-live video the advent of video embeds in HTML5 shows promise, and using Canvas and JavaSCript streaming should be technically possible, but handling streams and preloading binary video objects would have to be done in JavaScript and would not be very straightforward.

Comment: So are you saying that at this time there really isn't a good way to handle streaming with HTML5? If that's the case, then I guess I need to stop using HTML5, which is fine if there's another way to make video streaming work in a web browser. That's why I was trying to research some of the other options I mentioned in my question (e.g. RTSP). Are there no straightforward ways of implementing those other options either?

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say "preloading binary video objects". I'm not quite sure what how a video object would be binary. Does that just mean being able to turn the video off/on?